# Dynamic function signature based on available args?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, signature

I want to call function with dynamic signature based on what arg I have instantiated. The basic logic is:

```
if args is None and kwargs is None : return fun()
if args is not None and kwargs is None : return fun(*args)
if args is None and kwargs is not None : return fun(**kwargs)
if args is not None and kwargs is not None : return fun(*args,**kwargs)
```

Is there a shortcut way to do this?

The process is `__call__` stores the arguments, which are reused during op overloading `__rmod__`, which calls a wrapper around `fun()`.

The idea is to rework:

```
data % fun(args,kw) % .....
```

to:

```
fun(data,args,kw) % ......
```

Plus special handling when data is list-like structure; that's why a wrapper around `fun()` is needed.

Comment: the function is dynamically generated so it have specific but unknown signature

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass `fun(*args,**kwargs)` shouldn't the function be able to resolve if args or kwargs is empty?

Comment: yes .. arguments are stored in self.args/kwargs in `__call__`  and then reused in a wrapper around fun(), so wrapper has to call fun() with whatever was stored during `__call__` .. and self.args/kwargs has to be reset i.e. set to None between calls

Comment: `args = []; fun(*args)` acts exactly like `if args is None: fun()`…

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass it as:

```py
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is not a syntax erorr

lets say `args = []`

`print(*args)` will print nothing, it is not like args will contains a `None`

Comment: the problem is I have to store the arguments and then use them... how do I store no-arguments

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting them to `None` when empty, set `args` to an empty list and `kwargs` to an empty dict. Then you can just write `func(*args, **kwargs)` without worrying about whether they're set or not.

```
args = []
kwargs = {}
```

```
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```